# Why is C# truncating "00" to "0" when using ToString() method

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a unique value using a day,month,hour,minute and seconds. if i create the unique value at "2022/10/10 15:00:00" and i use ToString(), the "00" are truncated to "0"

```
var today = DateTime.Now;
string key = string.Format("341{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", today.Date.Day, today.ToString("MM"), today.Hour.ToString(), today.Minute.ToString(), today.Second.ToString());
```

Comment: There is no numerical value 00, that's just 0

Comment: If you do want two digits in the string representation, use `.ToString("00")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `00` value. It's [DateTime struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0) with `int` properties.

Use [interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) and proper [DateTime format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
string key = $"341{today:ddMMHHmmss}"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are much easier (and more consistent) means of formatting a DateTime into an output string.  Just use the ToString() method on your DateTime.

```
var dateStringIWant = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

More deets here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 0):

`today.Hour`, `today.Minute`, and `today.Second` are all integers, so the value you're converting to a string is the integer `0`, not `"00"`. Use `ToString("00")` if you want to preserve leading zeroes on them. Or just use a format string for the date to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string.Format("341{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", today.ToString("dd"), today.ToString("MM"), today.ToString("HH"), today.ToString("mm"), today.ToString("ss"));
```